# Dagger2 inject everything?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am reading documentation about [Dagger2](http://frogermcs.github.io/inject-everything-viewholder-and-dagger-2-example/). The thing is I have clear how inject a class how has `Context` using `this`

But my doubt is with the following class for example:

```
public class SocialControler{

private ImageView twitterLogo;
private ImageView googleLogo;

public SocialControler(ImageView twitter, ImageView google){
twitterLogo = twitter;
googleLogo = google;
}
//Getters and Setters

}
```

So in my `MainActivity` I will have something like this

```
SocialControler mSocial = new SocialControler(mTwitterLogo, mGoogleLogo);
```

Should I inject this class using `@Inject` anotation instead doing `new` , so no more `new` on our Activity? If yes How?

I am stuck in the `@Mudule` . How I can provide a View inside de `Module` ?

```
@Module
public class AppModuleSocialMediaManager {


    @Provides
    public MainActivity provideActivity(){
        return new MainActivity();
    }

    @Provides
    public SocialMediaClickManager provideMediaManager(MainActivity mainActivity, View twitterLogo, View googleLogo) {
        return new SocialMediaClickManager(mainActivity);
    }

    @Provides
    public View provideTwitter(){
        return ?
    //from here how I can provide a View
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get actually what you want, but you can provide the view passing the  MainActivity as parameter like  `@Provides public View provideTwitter(MainActivity activity){...}`

Comment: I want to know if we have to avoid to use new in our code and use @inject  for all the  clases we have using dagger2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend the architecture you're using to build your app, i.e. make your controllers depend on exact views, but if you're fine with that then you can implement your module like this:

```
 @Module
 public class AppModuleSocialMediaManager {
     private final MainActivity mainActivity;

     public AppModuleSocialMediaManager(MainActivity mainActivity) {
         this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
     }

     @Provides
     @Named("twitter_view")
     View provideTwitterView() {
         return mainActivity.findViewById(..);
     }

     @Provides
     @Named("google_view")
     View provideGoogleView() {
         return mainActivity.findViewById(..);
     }

     @Provides
     SocialController provideSocialController(@Named("twitter_view") View twitterView, @Named("google_view") View googleView) {
         return new SocialController(twitterView, googleView);
     }

 }
```

Then you need to declare another component. Let's say it's `MainActivityComponent`:

```
 @Component(modules = AppModuleSocialMediaManager.class)
 public interface MainActivityComponent {
     void inject(MainActivity activity);
 }
```

After that in your activity you can do something like this:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     @Inject
     SocialController socialController;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         DaggerMainActivityComponent.Builder()
             .appModuleSocialMediaManager(new AppModuleSocialMediaManager(this))
             .build()
             .inject(this);

         socialController.doSomething();
     }

 }
```

Comment: thanks a lot , what  do you mean  with -- make your controllers depend on exact views?

Comment: Your controller depends on views that comes from activity - twitter logo and google logo. Thus you can't unit test them because there's no such a thing as android view in unit tests for android. Basically, it just means that your code isn't decoupled and you mix models, views and business logic. Read about MVP for example https://github.com/konmik/konmik.github.io/wiki/Introduction-to-Model-View-Presenter-on-Android. It's quite popular right now. You may find ideas how to make your code better.

Comment: ah ok is for SocialControler.class Is not it? is just a class how control the state of a few animations over imagesViews on my MainActivity.

Comment: Nope. If you're going to make SocialController decouple then it should not controll animations. This class processes data and says to View(not Android view, view in the term of MVP) to start animations. So activity/fragment is the one who really moves views. Read something about MVP, MVC and MVVM. It gives your more clear ideas. This is not a topic that could be described in 5-10 sentences.

Comment: Don't try providing Views like this inside a Fragment unless you "unbind" them somehow in `onDestroyView()`

Comment: @DavidRawson Thanks a lot I will